# bind two events to one click with jquery.validate.js

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-validate, bind

Have two different events happening on the click. Using jQuery and trying to bind the to the submit button to different calls. One is a call to jquery.validate, the other is a call to a get response. Both of the events are working fine, but I want them tied together. Right now, the first click does a call to the server and receiving some JSON back (there's more code),

```
$("#validateButton").bind('click', function () {
  var someVariable = $("#someVariable").val();
}

 //Bind button to click
 $('#validateButton').bind('click', function () {
 //Implement Validate on this form ID
 $('#someForm').valid();
});
  //Ensure we're ready
$().ready(function () {


$("#someVariable").validate({

    rules: {
        someVariable: {
            required: true,
        },
    },

    messages: {
        accntTypeCL: {
            required: "Blah",

        },
    }
});

});
```

Comment: You should also show your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to bind `.valid()` to the click of the submit button because the form's status is already checked automatically when the submit is clicked.

You just use `.validate()` to initialize the form on DOM ready.  Then use its built in `submitHandler:` to do everything/anything else you need to do upon clicking the `submit` button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#theForm').validate() {
        // your validation rules and plugin options,

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // whatever code you want to run upon clicking submit
            var someVariable = $("#someVariable").val();
            form.submit();
        }
    });

});
```

**Simple Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/tyGNC/

Comment: I'll give this a shot. I think the issue is that I am using Worklight and using type="submit" instead of type="button" seems to upset the HTTP adapter that worklight uses to pass the JSON back and forth.